# How to identify an xml in a text file containing many xml files along with other text using the node of the xml in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I want to read the entire text file and fetch & save the entire second XML in my local drive based on the search input

Midnight Rain

Text File Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
controllercmds.statusupdate
ExtnClientExternalSrcProcess="9"
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>'
```

My Output should be :

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Is this doable ? Can someone help me out

Comment: Question not clear.. in which programming you are reading content of XML>

Comment: please paste the java code as well with which you have tried..

Comment: I tried using Buffered Reader                                                                                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       sftp.get(file.getFilename())));
     try {
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("<?xml version") {
         sb.append(line);

        }
       }
      System.out.println(sb);                               But it is taking too long to identify and append  the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should mention the programming language you are using so people can give you solutions with code anyway, for now I can think of regular expression can only be the solution and you have to know what will be the root tag your code should look for. like in above i can see  is the root tag. I'll try to compe up with code solution in few hours.

Following code works in JDK 6 and should work in later versions as well

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
"<catalog>" +
"<book id=\"bk101\">" +
   "<author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>" +
   "<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>" +
   "<genre>Computer</genre>" +
   "<price>44.95</price>" +
   "<publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>" +
   "<description>An in-depth look at creating applications" + 
   "with XML.</description>" +
"</book>" +
"</catalog>" +
"controllercmds.statusupdate" +
"ExtnClientExternalSrcProcess=\"9\"" +
"<catalog>" +
"<book id=\"bk102\">" +
   "<author>Ralls, Kim</author>" +
   "<title>Midnight Rain</title>" +
   "<genre>Fantasy</genre>" +
   "<price>5.95</price>" +
   "<publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>" +
   "<description>A former architect battles corporate zombies," + 
   "an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen " +
   "of the world.</description>" +
"</book>" +
"</catalog>";

String regex = "(\\<catalog\\>.*?\\</catalog\\>)";

java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml); 

while(matcher.find()) {

    System.out.println("Groups: " + matcher.group(1));
}

System.out.println("DONE");
```

output is

```
Groups: <catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applicationswith XML.</description></book></catalog>
Groups: <catalog><book id="bk102"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description></book></catalog>
DONE
```

[See your code running online here](https://ideone.com/UR58FG)

Comment: Thanks for your response Mubashar . I am trying to achieve this using Java language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Mubashar but i also need to search for the xml in the text file which is around 18-20 MB . Here i see you are passing the XML straightaway . Is that possible ?

Comment: with this solution you can read the file and pass the contents to this function. However 20 MB is kind of big so you can make it in chunks. but you have to be sure that each chunk at least contains one valid xml group.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case this is going to be difficult. But if you know that the input conforms to some particular constraints, it might be a lot easier. For example, if you know that the XML fragments will begin with `<catalog>` and end with `</catalog>` and if you have a high level of confidence that these two strings will not occur anywhere else, then extricating the XML fragments using regular expressions should not be too difficult. So I think the answer depends very much on what you know about the constraints, and on how much of a risk you are prepared to take in terms of the start/end tags "accidentally" (or maliciously!) appearing in unexpected places.